# How to provide selection options as response in ChatterBot

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am creating a chat bot using python chatter bot library. I am able to train the chat bot in the English language. Next thing I want to accomplish is to build a chat bot to provide selection options to the user for filtering the data.
Example: 
Request from user is Book a movie ticket.
I want to display the response as 3 buttons

In which time slot you want to book a movie ticket ?

a. Morning
 b. Afternoon
 c. Evening.

**Is there any feature in Python ChatterBot to send back selection options as response to the user.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that type of response using GuntherCox's chatterbot Library considering the last stable version.

Read the following documentation to know more: [Documentation Link](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#)

Else you can raise a issue and also here is their code base for your consideration to look deep down into it: [Github Link](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot)

Answer (score 0):

If you want intent and entity based chatbot you can look into Snips-nlu and Rasa.

https://github.com/snipsco/snips-nlu

https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa

So far what I have seen is that chatterbot can only provide static responses. Snips has module for generating `json` dataset from `yaml` file where you can define intents, entities, multiple slots etc.

https://snips-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataset.html

Rasa can provide what you are looking for. Provide response options based question. Provides easy training, HTTP API, python SDK etc.

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/rasa-tutorial/

Finally, this is a tool for generating training data for snips, rasa and others.

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/rasa-tutorial/

Comment: Hey @B200011011 Snips was acquired by Sonos (don't know if that was announced when you posted the answer though). I'm looking at Rasa but just reaching out to see if you can recommend more python bots. Above you state Rasa has an HTTP API b/c I'd like to have a bot give responses based on data it gets from an API. The docs mention it's only applicable for Docker container or testing locally though so I don't know if that'll accomplish it.

Comment: I am no longer working with Rasa but if remember correctly you do not docker to test http-api. You can look into for http-api here, https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/http-api/. For some NLP bots and libraries you can look here, https://github.com/quickgrid/AI-Resources. It may not be up to date.